# Problem applying the Hahn-Banach Theroem

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Let $M$ be a subspace and $\phi\in M^*$ and let $H=\{x\in M:\phi(x)=\|\phi\|\}$ and $U(M)=\{x\in M:\|x\|=1\}$. Suppose there exists a linear funtional $\psi\in X^*$ such that $\psi(x)<\gamma<\psi(y)$ for all $x\in U(M)$ and $y\in H$ and positive number $\gamma$. Let us extend $\phi$ to $X$ and call it $\phi$ again via Hahn-Banach Theorem.Choose any $\overline{x}\in X$ such that $\phi(\overline{x})=\|\phi\|$ and a $z\in X$ such that $\phi(z)=0$. This implies $\psi(\overline{x}+\lambda z)>\gamma$ for a real number $\lambda$. Then how do I prove that $\psi(z)=0$? I can deduce $\psi(z)>0$ but how do I deduce the reverse inequality? Or what am I missing?

Comment: I think $\overline x$ should be in $X$, not $X^*$.  Additionally, in the inequality $\psi(\overline{x}+\lambda \psi(z))>\gamma$, what is $\lambda$?

Comment: Yes. I corrected it and $\lambda$ is a real number. And, it is $\psi(\overline{x}+\lambda z)>\gamma$.